# If I know $\mathbb Z^3/L$, do I know $L$ up to isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Suppose I know $\mathbb Z^3/L = \mathbb Z_3 \oplus \mathbb Z_6 \oplus \mathbb Z$. How can I find $L$ up to $\cong$ (if possible at all)? ($L$ is a $\mathbb Z$-submodule of $\mathbb Z^3$)

In general, if I know what $M/N$ (modules) is, how can I know what $N$ is up to isomorphism?

Sorry if this is too basic. I tried to answer myself but I couldn't.

Answer (score 4):

If $L$ is a submodule of $M=\mathbb{Z}^n$ it is clear that $L$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module too, and you have just to find its rank (which is equal to the rank of $L$ minus the rank of $M/N$).

More in general, for a module $M$ and a submodule $N$, knowing the quotient $M/N$ is not enough. For example, if $M=\mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $M/N=\mathbb{Z}_2$, you have two different choice for $N$ not isomorphic:
$N=\mathbb{Z}_4$ and $N=\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$

Comment: You mean two different choices for $N$, not $M$, right?

Comment: @Ennar: Thanks, I've corrected it!

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb Z^3/L$ has rank $1$ and so $L$ has rank $2$. This determines $L$ up to isomorphism.

(But I think you had something else in mind.)

Note that $L = 3\mathbb Z \times 6\mathbb Z \times 0 \cong L' = 4\mathbb Z \times 5\mathbb Z \times 0$, even though $\mathbb Z^3/L \not \cong \mathbb Z^3/L'$.